# Anchor deploy --- Error: Custom: Invalid blockhash

Tags: rust, anchor, solana

Trying deploy a program to solana devnet.

I was using `anchor deploy` command.

```
Error: Custom: Invalid blockhash
There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.
```

I got this error.

OS: Ubuntu 21.10

Framework: anchor

Language: Rust

https://github.com/yeshealer/buildspace-anchor-epic-project

and This is my source project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to downgrade to anchor `0.18` ATM.

Answer (score 1):

The `Invalid blockhash` error means that one of the deploy messages timed out or was not part of the fork chosen by the network.  For devnet, you probably hit a timeout.  Typically, you just need to retry the deploy to get it to succeed, perhaps the network was falling behind.

More information about blockhashes in transactions at https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/transactions#recent-blockhash

Answer (score 0):

I recently started to learn Solana and Anchor development and experienced same issues.  It's really painful to have limited documentations. Here's what I found and how I deal with them. I think that there maybe some better ways to solve but since I'm new to this area. At least for now, it's temporary way for me.

[How to handle Solana Anchor deployment error and version switching error?](https://medium.com/@javaidea/how-to-handle-solana-anchor-deployment-error-and-version-switching-error-6a47fb821b20)